# config file for ASMX web service

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config, asmx

So I have made a web service in Visual Studio 2010. To deploy it onto the IIS web server, I copy the service.asmx, web.config, and the bin over to the server (wwwroot folder). This all works fine.

My problem is reading even a simple string from web.config. My code is:

In a method, I have:

```
string from = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folder_new"];
```

In the web.config file, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>    
  <appSettings>
    <add key="folder_new" value="C:\images\new" />
  </appSettings>
  <...other stuff etc...>
</configuration>
```

I read in from the location "from". If I change it to

```
string from = @"C:\images\new";
```

it works perfectly.

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Just a note: `from` isn't a great variable name.

Comment: BTW, were you aware that ASMX is a legacy technology that shouldn't be  used for new development?

Comment: Yeah it will be changed, just getting things working first

Comment: Responding to previous comment a bit late, but still: asmx is no legacy and is not deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) class instead of the `ConfigurationManager`. The interface on it is basically the same.

```
string notFrom =  
  System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folder_new"];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried double \'s in the config? Like `"c:\\images\\new"`

Comment: `\\` does not need to be escaped in XML.

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigurationManager` is for dealing with app config files for assemblies, rather than for Web.config files. Please use `WebConfigurationManager` instead.